# dotnet core assembly versioning and nuget package versioning

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

We're trying to find a solution to provide a single package name that identifies a version 1.x contract and a 2.x contract that are somewhat independent of each other.

Cosco.Contracts 1.x used on our api/foo 1.x

Cosco.Contracts 2.x used on our api/foo 2.x

The idea is to create a new Costco.Contracts 2.x project that references Costco.Contracts 1.x. The 1.x will inherit into 2.x. All in the same sln.

We'd like to avoid having a complete duplicate of 1.x for 2.x, therefore 2.x will inherit 1.x changes and in addition contain changes for our api/foo 2.x.

Each project will have their own build. Ideally 2.x will be backwards compatible.

When creating a nuget package as such `dotnet pack Costco.Contract.2.x.nupkg` we get an error

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\Serenity\Costco\Costco.Contracts.V2>dotnet pack Costco.Contracts --output D:\Jenkins\workspace\Serenity\Costco --configuration Release --include-source --include-symbols /p:PackageVersion=2.0.9-alpha /p:PackageID=Costco.Contracts
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for D:\Jenkins\workspace\Serenity\Costco\Costco.Contracts\Costco.Contracts.V2\Costco.Contracts.V2.csproj...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.103\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Ambiguous project name 'Costco.Contracts'.
```

I'm open to any suggestions, we just need a POC. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...after further research this is a bad idea.

Comment: well delete your question then